Downloading external resources is disabled
Tengo este error en eclipse, con un archivo xml que dice lo siguiente:
Downloading external resources is disabled (La descarga de recursos externos está deshabilitada).


Para solucionarlo, he ido al menú Window - Preferences y he buscado XML (Wild Web Developer)
Después he marcado el checkbox - Download external resources like referenced DTDm XSD

Por último he pulsado en Apply and Close y de esta forma ya no tengo error en mi xml.
Espero que sirva de ayuda a quien le pase lo mismo o si hay otras formas de solucionarlo, lo ponga por aquí.
Muchas gracias.
